# How to convert old version LitElement to new version

Tags: polymer, polymer-3.x, lit-element

I have developed the project using **`polymer (3.0.2)`** and **`lit-element (0.5.2)`**.

Now I want to convert this project to use the latest version of **`polymer (3.1.0)`** and **`lit-element (2.2.1)`**.

Is there any script or simple way to do these changes instead of changing the syntax in each and every file?

Comment: As far as I know, there isn't any script to automate this process

Answer (score 0):

I've been through this pain too - first from Polymer HTML Imports and then from Polymer to LitElement.

It's a little more complex than just changing syntax, which you can do fairly easily with regex/grep and the like, as there is a fundamental shift of approach.

Polymer relied heavily on two-way bindings - you put `<input value={{property}}>` and it would auto update. That relied on Polymer doing a lot of work and was fairly fragile - you were very limited about what you could build on top of it.

LitElement drops these - you have to do `<input value=${this.property} @change=${e => this.property = e.target.value}>` to explicitly handle changes. This lets LitElement be much smaller, much less opinionated, much more compatible with other libraries.

In addition LitElement components tend to be much more *functional* than Polymer ones. In Polymer you have lots of state properties/methods that you call from the template, while in LitElement those properties cause the `render` method to fire and are the starting point for building the template content.

So you can find-replace a lot of the components, and one way bindings (like `<input value=[[property]]>` to `<input value=${this.property}>`), but everything else needs to be adapted to LitElement's more bare-metal and functional approach.

On the plus side these *can* work side-by-side, so you can upgrade them one by one, but you have to do it manually.